# Brute force using python

Tags: python, brute-force

I have an executable program that takes in a four digit pin number as a combination. I am supposed to crack the program using a python script. So far I got this. When I execute this, it prints only 9999. So I get "Wrong pin code: 9999". Please help.

```
import itertools
import os

numbers = '0123456789'
y = ''
for c in itertools.product(numbers, repeat=4):
    pin = y+''.join(c)
print pin
os.system("./xyz "+pin)
```

Comment: You have an indentation problem. Your call to the OS is outside of the loop. As a side note, `y+''.join(c)` is exactly the same as `''.join(c)`, why bother.

Comment: ident the last 2 lines and you're good to go

Comment: Why are you using `y + ''.join(c)`? It's already a string, and Python doesn't need type coercion...

Comment: Using `itertools.product` is quite overkill for this. You want to loop from 0 to 9999, and format the number so it is always 4 numbers long, e.g. `for i in range(10000): pin = "{0:04d}.format(i)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take care of identation:

```
import itertools
import os

numbers = '0123456789'
y = ''
for c in itertools.product(numbers, repeat=4):
    pin = y+''.join(c)
    print pin
    os.system("./xyz "+pin)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your rapid reply. I am a noob in programming. It worked!

Answer (score 4):

as Maurice Meyer said: the indentation is wrong.

Also: using `itertools.product` for that is a bit complicated. I guess you want to solve to turn 1 into "0001", you can use `zfill` for that:

```
for i in range(10000):
    pin = str(i).zfill(4)
    os.system("./xyz "+pin)
```